# what is happening in this line of code in 0.1,0.1, what is used for in this line

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on the iris data sets as a begineer level so I have came across this code. I want to know what is happening in this code. I did not understand what does the `explode` and `0.1` are doing here:

```py
iris['variety'].value_counts().plot.pie((explode)=[0.1,0.1,0.1],autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=False,figsize=(100,8))
```

Comment: Mind formatting your code? Just edit your question, highlight the code and press `CTRL+K`

Answer (score 0):

This is badly written code. Actually, the parens around `explode` do absolutely nothing so it should be written as (I shortened the statement a bit for readability):

```
plot.pie(explode=[0.1,0.1,0.1], autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, figsize=(100,8))
```

IOW this is just a named argument like any other.